# Access javascript property inside object after declaration

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to make a class in javascript.

```
define(['knockout', 'knockout-validation', 'jquery'], function(ko, validation, $) {
    var SignUpViewModel = {
        name: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true
        }),
        email: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            email: true
        }),
        password: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true
        }),
        confirmPassword: ko.observable().extend({
            areSame: {
                params: password,
                message: "Repeat password must match Password"
            }
        }), // this line contains error . 
        register: function() {}
    }
    return SignUpViewModel;
});
```

Now its giving `undefined` error at password

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `this.password` to access it.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi `this` will be the window object here . So `this` will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object literals are not really optimal for Class creation. But they are a powerful tool, you can do it like this

```
(function(app) {
    app.define = function (definition) {
        definition.prototype = definition.prototype || {};
        definition.init.prototype = definition.prototype;
        definition.init.prototype.constructor = definition.init;

        return definition.init;
    };

})(window.app = window.app || {});
```

Use it like

```
app.define({
   init: function() {
        this.password = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

        this.confirmPassword = ko.observable().extend({
            areSame: {
                params: this.password,
                message: "Repeat password must match Password"
            }
        });
   },
   prototype: {
      register: function() {
      }
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ak2Ej/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how you're calling `callitfunction`, but if it's like this:

```
mytestobj.callitfunction();
```

...then `this.password` will be defined within the call.

```
console.log("The password is " + this.password()); // Since password is a KO observable, it's a function, so use () on it
```

Alternately, as that's a one-off object, just use `mytestobj.password`. E.g.:

```
console.log("The password is " + mytestobj.password());
```

...and then you're not relying on `this`.

Note that `this` within a JavaScript function call is determined primarily by *how the function is called*, rather than where the function is defined as in some other languages. So for instance, `this` will not be `mytestobj` here:

```
var f = mytestobj.callitfunction;
f(); // `this` is not `mytestobj` within the call
```

More:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

Comment: i explained my question and told my real scenario . So that i can get help more specifically . See my edit .